# why won't php 5.3.3 compile libphp5.so on redhat ent

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php5, rhel5

I'm trying to upgrade to php 5.3.3 from php 5.2.13. However, the apache module, libphp5.so will not be compiled. Below is a output I got along with the configure options I used. The configure statement is a reduced version of what I normally use.

==========

'./configure' '--disable-debug' '--disable-rpath' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs'

...

** ** ** Warning: inter-library dependencies are not known to be supported.
** ** ** All declared inter-library dependencies are being dropped.

** ** ** Warning: libtool could not satisfy all declared inter-library
** ** ** dependencies of module libphp5.  Therefore, libtool will create
** ** ** a static module, that should work as long as the dlopening
** ** ** application is linked with the -dlopen flag.
copying selected object files to avoid basename conflicts...
Generating phar.php
Generating phar.phar
PEAR package PHP_Archive not installed: generated phar will require PHP's phar extension be enabled.
clicommand.inc
pharcommand.inc
directorytreeiterator.inc
directorygraphiterator.inc
invertedregexiterator.inc
phar.inc

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

=============

php 5.2.13 recompiles just fine so something is up with 5.3.3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately have the same problem, where PHP 5.3.2 compiles just fine with the same configure statement.

This makes me think that something might have broken on certain platforms (mine included) when 5.3.3 was released.

I have an open bug for this at http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53116

Comment: I would like to add that if you are in a hurry to get to the new features in 5.3 that you should try 5.3.2 - You shouldn't have any problems getting it to compile, and when we figure out what's wrong in compiling 5.3.3 you'll already have new code to run on it.